# iOS Firebase - print(snapshot.value) to TableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I am connecting my firebase database with my Xcode Project. I have successfully used the print(snapshot.value) to print my snapshot of the database into the console. However, I am struggling to print my snapshot of data into the TableView. Thank you.

Here is my code :

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UITableViewController {



@IBOutlet var cosmos: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var gallonsTXT: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var tables: UITableView!


@IBOutlet var Finale: UILabel!
var ref:DatabaseReference?
var databaseHandle:DatabaseHandle?
var postData = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    gallonsTXT.delegate = self
    gallonsTXT.dataSource = self

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    databaseHandle = ref?.child("Total gallons:").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        print(snapshot.value) 

        let post = snapshot.value as? String

        if let actualPost = post {

            self.postData.append(actualPost)

        self.tableView.reloadData()


        }

    })
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typic    ally from a nib.
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return postData.count

}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = postData[indexPath.row]

    return cell!
}


}
```

Comment: Are you sue snapshot.value gives a String? It normally returns a Dictionary

Comment: in the console it says the following :

Comment: optional : 0.263

Comment: which is the correct data from my database

Comment: however I want that number (data) to go into the table view

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your view did load to the following. You must declare a dictionary in order to properly read and use data from Firebase.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    gallonsTXT.delegate = self
    gallonsTXT.dataSource = self

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    databaseHandle = ref?.child("Total gallons:").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        print(snapshot.value) 

        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
        let post = dict["your data key"] as! String

        self.postData.append(actualPost)
        self.tableView.reloadData()

              }

    })
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typic    ally from a nib.
}
```

If this does not work, force unwrap the text in your text field and see if it produces a nil error. in `CellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: I have tried your first option. It still hasn't printed my data onto the storyboard. The main issue I am facing is printing the data that appeared in my console, right into the storyboard. Please help thanks.